# Issues with multiple languages (django.po file)

Tags: django, django-multilingual

I am using the concept of multiple languages in my app and for that I have done all those things which are written in the doc.

But when I creates a locale file inside my project and then the respective language folder "es" and thus a by default django.po file is created which contains all the lines which I can edit .

e.g.

```
#: customer_reg/my_new_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/global_settings.py:48
msgid "Arabic"
msgstr ""
```

But this django.po file  does not contain my app templates files which I can edit.

As i said I have created this locale file inside my project parallel to my app,I don't know why it happens.
So I have to create this inside my app parallel to my models and views ?? OR there is any another problem ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the locale directory in your app, at the same level where your settings.py file exists.

Now from the previous level i.e. where you created the locale directory, type the cmd to generate a source file[.po].
cmd like ./manage.py makemessages -l [language code]
Check the language code from http://translate.sourceforge.net/wiki/l10n/pluralforms

Tada..! 
this should work for you, will incude your app templates.

Let me know if this doesnt work for u.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..........I have already did it , the same way as you mentioned..... By the thanks for the reply once again !!!